# Merge 2 screen with 2 entities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I had 4 UITableView which represents 4 tabs from my UITabBar. So I have an unique custom TableViewController which controls every screen depending on the entity (on CoreData) it has to display.
In order to fetch elements from CoreData I use a NSFetchedResultsController.

But my problem is, for marketing reasons, I have to merge 2 screens which means displaying 2 entities in the same screen. So I have to fetch elements from 2 different entities. I also have an abstract entity "Element" which is a SuperClass that I use in my TableViewController to control each entity abstractly.

What is the best solution ?

- Do I have to rewrite my Model to merge those 2 entities (this is a problem because the 2 entities are a bit different)
- Can I tell to my NSFetchedResultsController to fetch 2 entities ? How ?
- Can I tell to my NSFetchedResultsController to fetch the Element entity and afterwards to predicate those Entities ? How ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that I havn't proposed.

I have added a new Abstract Entity which is a superclass for the 2 I wanted to merge but which is an "element" child also.

So my ElementListViewController still show "Elements" and I can show the merged Entity for my screen.

I'm now working on migrating old model into new one.

May this post be helpful one day ...

Answer (score 0):

the best solution out of the three would be to fetch the Element entity with the correct predicate. NSfetchRequest can only fetch one entity..

I would also consider a different approach that would satisfy your marketing needs. You could just perform two different fetches and than combine the results..

Comment: For the first solution, how do you tell to your predicate to take only SubElementA and SubElementB ? Is there a "kindOf" in predicate ?

Comment: not that i know of, but since the entities are different you can leverage that to distinguish between them..